# AutoKey Python - How do I create a global function library

Tags: python, namespaces, autokey

I'm using [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/) (not AutoHotKey), and I'm noticing that multiple scripts are using the same python functions I've created. Up until now, I've just been defining the same function in each script that uses it. However, if I have to go back and modify that function, I have to remember each script that uses it, and make those modifications for each one.

Using AutoKey, how would I have (custom) global function library, that I'd be able to import into each script, so I'll have a centralized place for propagating function modifications to all scripts?

I've just begun using python (because AutoKey uses it for its scripting engine), so I'm not sure how I'd create my own namespace and I'm also not sure how I'd import a custom library into my AutoKey python scripts. Where would I place the code-file? What would the syntax be inside the file that will be encapsulating my function definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a module and put it in the `Lib\site-packages` folder of Python.

For example, with this:

```
def foo():
    print("foo called")
```

stored as `C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\foo.py`:

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.foo()
foo called
```

Answer (score 3):

Using recent AutoKey versions, you can set the preference "User Module Folder" in the "Script Engine" tab to a folder of your liking.